# Update and return updated objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Is it possible to do an update on a model, and then have all the updated objects returned. I'm using postgresql, and it has this `RETURNING` clause option. It would be great if it was possible to do something like this:

```
User.where(name: 'Adam').udpate_all(has_nice_name: true).returning("*")
#=> [User, User, User]
```

That would essentially execute something like this on the db:

```
UPDATE users SET has_nice_name = 't' WHERE users.name = 'Adam' RETURNING *;
```

This would be very useful performance vice.

Comment: standard rails methods do not provide this possibility

Comment: Why don't you just create an instance variable - this will be populated wit the updated data from the database, surely?

Comment: @RichPeck I don't think I get your point?

Comment: You mention you want to "return the updated object" - I was asking that if you update the object in the database, surely you'll get the updated object anyway?

Comment: Note that that I'm not doing the update on an instance of a `User`, it's done on the class (`update_all`).